# Why is ksh script exit code 1 after while loop?

Tags: ksh, aix

I typically write Perl scripts, but I'm modifying a legacy KSH script (so I don't have to rewrite the entire thing) that sets a counter equal to the number of items in an array, then executes a while loop that decrements the counter so I can assign a value to a variable in a specific order. However, when I do this, the exit code is 1, instead of 0.

Here's the code ():

```
set -A MY_ARRAY item1 item2
i=${#MY_ARRAY[@]}
while [[ ${i} -gt 0 ]]; do
    (( j = ${#MY_ARRAY[@]} ))
    if [[ ${i} -ge ${j} ]]; then
        x="first value"
    else
        x="second value"
    fi

    (( i = i - 1 ))
done
```

When the above code runs, the exit code is 1. I would presume that this is because the condition during the last attempted iteration is `[[ 0 -gt 0 ]]` and because this test is false, the return value in $? is 1. However, the exit code is 0 if I write the following:

```
i=0
if [[ ${i} -gt 0 ]]; then
    x="first value"
else
    x="second value"
fi
```

If the issue is because the condition at the last iteration is false, what would be the best way to handle this? Would it be to set the return value immediately after the 'done' line, like this:

```
done || return 0
```

or

```
done || exit 0
```

Or would it be to set the return/exit value on a subsequent line after the 'done' line, like this:

```
done
return 0
```

or

```
done
exit 0
```

Otherwise, what am I missing/doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: a good set of suppositions/questions. You can test these assumptions yourself by adding `export PS3='$LINENO >' ; set -vx` as the 2nd line of your script. You'll see each group of commands before being executed (the whole while loop, for instance) and then lines preceded with `+` (and `3 >` (LINENO)) showing the actual values of variables as each line is executed. Sometimes hard to tell what is what, you may have to enhance debug output like `print -- -u2 "#DBG: i=$i \tj=$j ..."`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The while loop will return the exit code of the last command in the loop (when looped at least once):

```
j=1
while [ $j -gt 0 ]; do
   ((j--))
   true
done
echo "$? after true"
j=1
while [ $j -gt 0 ]; do
   ((j--))
   false
done
echo "$? after false"
```

In your case, try the following commands to see the return value:

```
j=5; ((j = j - 1 )); echo "$j returns $?"
j=1; ((j = j - 1 )); echo "$j returns $?"
```

I think the exit/return code you want to have is not the value of the loop.
Consider:

```
function count_highvalues {
   retval=0
   while [[ ${i} -gt 0 ]]; do
      (( j = ${#MY_ARRAY[@]} ))
      if [[ ${i} -ge ${j} ]]; then
         ((retval++))
      fi
      ((i--))
   done
   return ${retval}
}
```

Just leave the while-do-done doing the things you ask and return/exit what you want.
Try to make the return/exit value 0 something that van be considered OK / true.

Sometimes you want an exit, sometimes a return. An exit will finish the current script, and a return only the current function.
Try the following code: You will not see "After f2", since the script has exited.

```
function f1 {
   return 1
}

function f2 {
   exit 2
}

echo "Before f1"
f1
echo "After f1: $?"
echo "Before f2"
f2
echo "After f2: $?"
```

Comment: Do you know why I'm getting a 1 when I `echo $?` after running the script? Based on your comment, I take it that you're recommending that I put my code in a function with a specified return value. I think that could work for me, although based on what you've said, I really just need to put an exit 0 after my while loop (since that's the end of the code in my script). I'm just not clear on why the while loop or the test condition, or whatever may be causing the 1 exit code, is occurring.

Comment: You do not need a function and can use exit. Return is valid in a function, so for showing the difference between exit and return, I gave a function as example.

Comment: Edited the question for the exit value of the `while`.

Comment: I tried `j=5; ((j = j - 1)); echo "$j returns $?"` and `j=1; ((j = j - 1)); echo "$j returns $?"`. The output of the first statement is "4 returns 0" and the output of the second is "0 returns 1". So, my question was, why is `$?` exit code returning `1` in the second statement when `$j = 0`? Is `$?` always going to equal `1` when the result of a calculation on a variable equals `0`? However, I found the answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63306.